# Got white screen and horizontal gray lines

Tags: windows-7

My Aspire one 756 877B1 screen just turn to white with gray horizontal lines. I never have dropped it since I bought it last year? what could possibly this be?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your screen is damaged.
If you have video out, you could connect it up to something else (tv, monitor etc) and see if you get a picture. That would rule out the video card.

It sounds like it might still be in Warranty, so make use of that.